# Graphically representing data in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

In Python, I have two 2D arrays with each element of the main arrays containing a smaller array which contains the X and Y positions of two objects (One array for each object) at a moment in time, each array functions as a record of each objects X and Y positions over time. How can I graphically represent this data?, I would like to be able to later add a third object with its own array or maybe expand this into 3D(this would mean 3 elements for each of the smaller arrays x,y and z), I want to be able to put this data into some graph so I can visually see how it changes over time, any help would be appreciated.

I'm stuck, I don't know what to try to represent this data.

```
while time < TotalTime:
    objectACurrentPos = [aXpos, aYpos]
    objectBCurrentPos = [bXpos, bYpos]

    objectAposHistory.append(objectACurrentPos)
    objectBposHistory.append(objectBCurrentPos)
```

this is the inside of a while loop that will iterate anywhere between 1500 and 15000 times so objectAposHistory and objectBposHistory will be quite large

Comment: Have a look at the Panda’s library

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries for data visualization. The most commons ones are probably `pandas` and `matplotlib`. `numpy` is also good for processing your data.